# Flatten Object in Linq using c#

Tags: c#, linq, flatten

I have an Data object that has been deserialized from a json response that has properties in the format of:

[0] ....

GroupName: "Group 1"

Memberlist: [String array of UserIDs]

[1]

GroupName: "Group 2"

Memberlist: [String array of UserIDs]

.

. etc

I would like to flatten this out so that it simply returns 2 columns like:

userID, Name

1, Group 1

2, Group 1

3, Group 1

4, Group 2

5, Group 2

and so on.

UserIDs are unique across all groups that is a user is only a member of 1 group

I have tried with:

```
var group = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(<My Json File>);
var gpObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GroupDetailResponse>(group.ToString());
var memberGroup = gpObject.Data.Select(y => new { UserId = y.Memberlist.SelectMany(sl => y.memberlist).ToArray(), GroupName = y.Id }).ToArray();
```

But this doesnt return what i was expecting above.

Any help will be appreciated - thanks.

JSON SNIPPET:

```js
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "ZZ1",
      "name": "Group1",
      "memberList": [
        "User1",
        "User2",
        "User3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ZZ2",
      "name": "Group2",
      "memberList": [
        "User4",
        "User5"
      ],
    }
   ]
```

And the DTO:

```
public class GroupDetailResponse
    {

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public GroupInformation[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class GroupInformation
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("memberList")]
        public string[] MemberList { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better, if you posted a sample of the json object, also what is the type being deserialized to in the first line/ show `GroupDetailResponse` class?

Comment: Have added those details above now. Apologies for being vague!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var memberGroup1 = gpObject.SelectMany(x => x.Memberlist, (group, id) => new { id, group.GroupName});
```

If you pass a result selector function to your SelectMany call, you can use it to merge the "parent (GroupName in this case) with the "child" values (User Ids in this case) together.

This blog does a good job of explaining the usage of SelectMany to flatten objects, including using the result selector: http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/